# Two list views of same list in a Page. Applying JS link - CSR to create charts using Charts.js

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, client-side-rendering, chart

Following this [Article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59630fd6-5c9c-42d6-8750-d9a087bbc4c4/chartsjs-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

**Scenario:** To create charts. Using chart.js + jquery + **Demochart.js** file I have modified using the one given in article. I have two list view webparts in same page. So I apply these JS links to first List view webpart it works but the second list view does not show. I use first list view webpart's **View ID** (taken from SPdesigner) to distinguish between webparts...so JSlinks affect only the first one.

Am I using **Demochart.js** the right way?

***Code of Demochart.js:***

```
// Declare the variables.
var sitesChart = sitesChart || {};

sitesChart.Colors = ['#1BA1E2', '#E51400', '#339933','#56348E'];

sitesChart.ChartTitle =[];
sitesChart.ChartT1 = [];
sitesChart.ChartT2 = [];
sitesChart.ChartT3= [];


sitesChart.Desc = '';

// Override the rendering.
sitesChart.FieldRenderSetup = function (ctx) {
    var override = {};
    override.Templates = {};
    override.Templates.Header = sitesChart.CustomHeader;
    override.Templates.Item = sitesChart.CustomItem;
    override.Templates.Footer = sitesChart.CustomFooter;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(override);
};


sitesChart.CustomItem = function (ctx) {
        var str = ctx.view.toString();

        //Using Webpart view id to distinguish between webparts 
        if(ctx.view === "{3FE32257-65DA-467F-919B-16B742BA932E}"){
            sitesChart.ChartTitle.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);//columns names
            sitesChart.ChartT1.push(parseInt(ctx.CurrentItem.Team1));//columns names
            sitesChart.ChartT2.push(parseInt(ctx.CurrentItem.Team2));//columns names
            sitesChart.ChartT3.push(parseInt(ctx.CurrentItem.Team3));//columns names
        }
        return '';
}


sitesChart.CustomHeader = function (ctx) {
    return "<canvas id='lineChart' width='700' height='400' style='float:left;margin-right:20px;'></canvas>";
}

// Override the footer.
sitesChart.CustomFooter = function () {

    var data = {
        labels: sitesChart.ChartTitle,
        datasets: [
        {
            label: "Team1",
            fill: false,
            borderColor: sitesChart.Colors[0],
            pointBorderColor: sitesChart.Colors[0],
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            data: sitesChart.ChartT1
        },
        {
            label: "Team2",
            fill: false,
            borderColor: sitesChart.Colors[1],
            pointBorderColor: sitesChart.Colors[1],
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            data: sitesChart.ChartT2
        },
        {
            label: "Team3",
            fill: false,
            borderColor: sitesChart.Colors[2],
            pointBorderColor: sitesChart.Colors[2],
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            data: sitesChart.ChartT3
        }
        ]
    }

    // Line chart options.
    var options = {
        responsive: false,
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        scaleStepWidth: 10,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
        pointDotRadius: 7,
        datasetFill: false
    };


    var chart = $('#lineChart').get(0).getContext("2d");

    new Chart(chart, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: options
    });

    return '';
}

$(document).ready(sitesChart.FieldRenderSetup());// JavaScript source code
```

Before applying:

[image]

After applying:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show chart in second webpart also, then remove `if(ctx.view === "{3FE32257-65DA-467F-919B-16B742BA932E}")` condition from `sitesChart.CustomItem`

If you want to show default list view for the second webpart then do as below

```
//In CustomItem function
if(ctx.view === "{3FE32257-65DA-467F-919B-16B742BA932E}"){
//Your code
}
return RenderItemTemplate(ctx); //write this line instead return ''

//In CustomHeader function
if(ctx.view === "{3FE32257-65DA-467F-919B-16B742BA932E}"){
//Your code
}
return RenderHeaderTemplate(ctx);

//In CustomFooter function
if(ctx.view === "{3FE32257-65DA-467F-919B-16B742BA932E}"){
//Your code
}
return RenderFooterTemplate(ctx);
```

Comment: As you said i've applied these changes see -> https://pastebin.com/PhKtn7vC

Comment: You have not added 'return RenderHeaderTemplate(ctx);' in CustomHeader

Comment: there is a canvas being returned in that line... The chart may not show if I don't return it?!?  ... im not sure. Let me see!

Comment: It gives error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined**  

See->https://imgur.com/a/Dm4O2
Code->https://pastebin.com/fVzYb1Gh

Comment: uncomment "return <canvas id='lineChart' ..>" in CustomHeader and try again

Comment: I've uncommented the 'return canvas' line..apart from that the code is same. Problem is I looked at the page code in SP Designer only thing which distinguishes these list views is View ID...  BaseViewID and everything else is same. 

First webpart view id = {3FE32257-65DA-467F-919B-16B742BA932E}
2nd webpart view id = {31BD318D-04D3-4B78-8F50-30855F8D5B75}

Comment: Success with this code... i added `return '';` in `If {...}` see code -> https://pastebin.com/NGVuNcgU 

But now also want to have different chart(say bar chart) in second list view.. so I changed the View ID in `If(ctx.view = ...)` saved the code with different name, added in the JSlink but now the 1st list view appears as list second one appears as chart... ?! see here->https://imgur.com/a/jAHw2VT

Comment: Don't use different file for other webpart. Try to adjust code in else block for Item, Header and Footer of first file only. When you use different file, all file's code execute one after other, only last file webpart will use jslink other will render as default list view because of RenderItemTemplate(ctx)

Comment: I apply JSlink in this manner:

**1st webpart** = ~site/SiteAssets/ChartFiles/jquery.min.js|~site/SiteAssets/ChartFiles/Chart.js|~site/SiteAssets/ChartFiles/Demochart.js



**2nd webpart** = ~site/SiteAssets/ChartFiles/jquery.min.js|~site/SiteAssets/ChartFiles/Chart.js|~site/SiteAssets/ChartFiles/Demochart2.js

Comment: So the code in one of the Demochart.js files should be altered and applied to any one of the webparts. Do you have any preliminary guideline for CSR code esp. the one i'm using now.. bcz I do understand the javascript code etc but i'm finding it difficult to join points in sense 'what goes where'